# Evaluate Spark Inside Scala ToolBox

Tags: scala, apache-spark, runtime, scala-reflect

Can I evaluate spark inside scala toolbox? I need to read something with spark within the toolbox, my code looks like this:

```
object Something extends SparkScript {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val command =
      s"""
        |import spark.implicits._
        |
        |val ds = spark.read.parquet("$path").as[SomeGeneric]
        |ds.write.csv("$anotherPath")
        |""".stripMargin

    val toolBox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    toolBox.eval(toolBox.parse(command))
  }
}
```

By the way, the `SparkScript` is a trait that create a `SparkSession`
the toolbox always throw an error that said `object read is not a member of spark`

Comment: You need to put everything you want/need to use inside the toolbox, it is like a different scope

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís so, to make it work, i need to create a sparksession inside the toolbox ?, because i did import the sparksession from `Something` inside the toolbox but it still didn't work

Comment: Could you put the trait SparkScript and the imports for reflection, so I could try it out? I never did something like that with Spark @afghifari

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís i finally figure it out, just like you said, i need to import the sparksession inside the toolbox

Comment: @afghifari can you post your final solution, I am looking for something like this, thanks!